# How to show text in page footer in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have added a page footer into crystal report but it is only showing at second page and not showing at first page. Image has been uploaded. More specifically
Text admin (Exam) and Assistant is not showing at every page. Although I have written the same text in page footer, (you can see picture for better understanding) but it is not showing....

**Design File**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: If my answer is wrong, show us the screenshot of your designer in Crystal Reports.

Comment: Dear, I have shared design file..

Comment: how many pages are there in preview?

Comment: it is dynamically, maybe two or three

Comment: You mentioned a formula about _supression_. Where did you put it? Can you add it in your question?

Comment: reverse the supression formula for page footer and report footer and check the result